# How to give parameters in the url?

Tags: html, url, webforms, parameters, search-box

*The question raised from the question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058275/how-do-browsers-search-boxes-work). In order to have search engines in Browser, I need to find a way to get the parameters to url.*

Suppose you have Google Sites where you have Google Gadget. The gadget has a search box.

How can you give the search parameters to the search box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is described in the HTML 4.01 specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3

Essentially you append a "?" to the URI, then create sets of key=value pairs which have special characters represented by escape sequences. Then append the pairs to the URL, separating each pair with an ampersand or semi-colon.

Comment: There is one problem. You have the interanal search and the CSE, both of which uses the "q"- parameter. Above all, the CSE seems to work somehow differently: http://sites.google.com/site/mathharbour/Search-math/mathematics-definitions/beta/alpha/faq/testing. If you had the CSE in its basic site, like http://www.google.com/cse?cx=007883453237583604479%3A6hceebmys3e&ie=UTF-8&q=math&sa=Search, there would be no problem. Now, I cannot see how the link solves the problem.

Comment: I am confused because of the new layour in which the engine is encapsulated. Not sure how it works.

Comment: You can count me out for any interanal searches.